# Shortcut key for Terminator lands in the "/" directory

Tags: shortcut-keys

I bound the command "terminator" to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in the shortcut keys configuration.

This is nice and all except terminator starts with `/` as the current directory, not `~`. How to change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to update the shortcut to the following command:

```
terminator --working-directory=~
```

From the [MAN page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/terminator.1.html):

> ```
>    --working-directory=DIR
>           Set the terminal's working directory
> ```

Comment: Much appreciation, my good man. Read the manual, completely missed this :)

Answer (score 4):

Run the command as

```
terminator --working-directory=~
```

instead of just

```
terminator
```